# How to use gulp 4 to call other tasks?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have the following task

```
gulp.task("all", gulp.parallel("js", "css"));
```

The "all" task simply calls the "js" and "css" task.

But when I run it, I get this

```
The following tasks did not complete: all, js, css
Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

I tried changing my code to this

```
function runAll(done) {
    gulp.parallel("js", "css",;

    done();
}
gulp.task("all", runAll);
```

I no longer get the message, the but I don't get a message that shows that the "js" and "css" tasks completed

How can I correctly call both "js" and "css" tasks from "all"task?

**Updated**

Here is my js task

```
gulp.task("js", function () {

    console.log('calling js');
    var tasks = gulp.src(['path1', 'path2'], { base: "." })
            .pipe(filter('**/*.js'))
            .pipe(concat('output.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("."))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("."));

    return merge(tasks);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your `js` and `css` tasks are signalling completion?

Comment: Yes, you should edit your question to show the `js` and `css` tasks as well - the problem may be there.

Comment: @Mark I updated my question with the `js` task

Comment: I don't think it is a problem but there is no reason for the `var tasks = ` part of the `js` task.  You could just do a simple `return gulp.src...` there and get rid of the `return merge(tasks)`.  See if it makes a difference and post the `css task as well.